# Is there some program to speak on the micropohone and get the recognized text along with a translation to other language

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a sowftware where I can speak to the microphone and get the recorgnized text and also a suggested translation in a different format.

The objective is to help people have written online conversations in languages that are not their own.

I saw many speech-to-text projects and also translating apps, but none that seems to combine them for this particular purpose.

The ideal thing would be something like google translate, but instead (or in addition to) writing the text I could just speak to the microphone (or perhaps a different app to do that)

> I found out that I was missing the mic icon in Google translate, I switched to google chrome and it worked.

Comment: There are excellent web services which will convert speech to text, and you will have to another web service for the translation. I don't know if there is a single service or software which does both of these simultaneously.

Comment: Do you tried [google translator](https://translate.google.com/) ?

Comment: Have you tried asking on [SE Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?newreg=644f2ca223894d43a51600e7df318c7d)? Don't forget to mention your OS to narrow down the suggestions to those appropriate for you.

Comment: done -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81354/is-there-some-program-to-speak-on-the-micropohone-and-get-the-recognized-text-al
thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record I'll post the solution I found so far:

- Add the [Voice In Voice Typing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-in-voice-typing/pjnefijmagpdjfhhkpljicbbpicelgko/related?hl=en) extension to Chrome
- Goto to [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) online translator

that's it

> I couldn't find a way to make [punctuation marks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-punctuation) work with google translate, so I switched to VoiceIn that works great with [punctuation marks](https://dictanote.co/voicein/voicecommands/es/)